# PHP artisan command has no effect

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, hosting, laravel-artisan

I created a project in Laravel 5, on localhost. It works perfectly. I uploaded it on Godaddy using FileZilla and tried to run `php artisan` command. It didn't work. Just to be sure if there's a problem with composer or Laravel, I created a new Laravel project with same name and tried `php artisan` command it worked. Then I tried copying just app and database folder into newly created project and tried `php artisan` command, it stopped working just like before.

[image: screenshot]

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here.

I tried running `composer install` command in project directory as per one suggestion on stackoveflow, didn't work for me

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You should try "php artisan cache:clear" and then run again. Also, it seems like you have two migrations that try to create users table, you could encounter some bugs in the future because of that.

Comment: @Timo Still no effect

Comment: "composer dump-autoload" and "php artisan dump-autoload"?

Comment: @Timo same no effect

Answer (score 1):

There probably is something in the `app/` or `database/` directory that's causing some fatal error and your php configuration is set to not display any errors.

Execute `php --ini` to find out which ini file is used and then configure it to show errors. After saving the ini file, run `php artisan` again and fix the error.

Comment: Actually there was problem with permissions. So I applied 755 to everything under project folder and it worked.